# ошибка при сберке проекта на webpack с babel

Tags: node.js, webpack, babel, runtime

Ошибка при сборке вызвана после следующих манипуляций.

Создан файл, в который добавлен класс, потом этот класс импортирован в основной (головной) файл `import {DutyShift} from "./duty_shift";`.

Как только добавляется данная строка, сразу выскакивает ошибка снизу.

При сберке проекта возникает следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR in ./www/web/js/duty_shift.js 1:0-72
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck' in '/usr/local/niissu/center-m/branches/lobasov/centervdv_dev/www-test/www/web/js'
 @ ./www/web/js/index.js 3:0-41 5:27-36

ERROR in ./www/web/js/duty_shift.js 2:0-66
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createClass' in '/usr/local/niissu/center-m/branches/lobasov/centervdv_dev/www-test/www/web/js'
 @ ./www/web/js/index.js 3:0-41 5:27-36

webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 2 errors in 585 ms
[webpack-cli] watching files for updates...
```

Файл package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Тест",
  "private": true,
  "author": "***",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "Firefox 29",
    "safari 5"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.8.55",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "webix": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "twig-html-loader": "^0.1.8",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "webpackbar": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "testDev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development --config webpack.test.config.js --progress",
    "testDevW": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development --config webpack.test.config.js --watch",
    "testPro": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.test.config.js"
  }
}
```

Файл конфигурации babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "corejs": 3,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "29",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1"
        },
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-function-bind"],
    ["@babel/transform-runtime", {
      "regenerator": true,
      "useESModules": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: возможно export потеряли в duty_shift

Comment: Экспорт есть. Да и IDE сама подсказывает :)